# HTML5 Custom Data Attributes in TYPO3 Backend Content Elements

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am wondering if there is a way to add a HTML5 Custom Data Attribute to any Content Element like Text or Text w/ images.

Anyone tried / did this before or is there a good reason not to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can either add a new field (own extension) or use any of the existing (e.g. `layout` to define own values. Then you can change the `TypoScript` rendering based on the value of this field.

Answer (score 1):

... or in addition to @pgampe's answer, which is fine for programmers you can use ie. [DCE](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/dce) extension, which allows you to create any HTML structure with usage pure Fluid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for the answers. I didn't know DCE, looks very interesting.

As I needed a quick solution for just a few elements on one page I did something really quick and dirty. But as it worked for me, I would like to post it in addition to the two other excellent answers.

I used the field Description field to add the content of my custom field. I know it's not intended for this, but as alreay mentioned: quick & dirty. :-)

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
    50 =< tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default
    50.20.10.value = csc-default layout-{field:layout}" data-filter="{field:rowDescription}
    50.20.10.insertData = 1
}
```

Comment: Careful here. With your solution, editors can insert arbitrary HTML, including XSS and other HTML based attacks on the frontend. So make sure to either not allow this field for editors or to really **trust** your editors. Or you change the full TS rendering and sanitize the field properly.